# Open source library in Swift project causing signing error when running on real device

Tags: ios, swift, code-signing

I am writing a library, which also imports another library that is an opensource project.

I've built my library and a test app that makes use of my library and the open source imported library and everything works perfectly fine when working on the iOS simulator.

However, as soon as I try running it from xcode to a physical device, the physical device receives a SIGABRT with the following error:

> not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has
> no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

The error is regarding the opensource library that is imported into my library but not sure what the issue is here as the signing I believe is set up the same as my app. Below is a screenshot of the library signing settings.

[image: Screenshot showing signing]

If you need any more info then please let me know, I'm very new to Swift and iOS/Xcode in general.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15645#issuecomment-554495051 this might help

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to make difference.